# TYPO3 10 .htaccess redirect old links to new links not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3, typo3-10.x

While updating a website (completely new page tree, IDs have changed), the old links need to redirect to the new links. Domain stays the same.

This is the first thing I write in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.php?id=5 /contact
Redirect 301 /test.html /xy.html
Redirect 301 /index.php?id=6 /imprint
# and many more
```

**test.html** successfully links to xy.html (just a test, they don't even exist and correctly show the 404 page)
the **index.php?id=x** redirects however do not work. They actually still open whatever new page has this ID.

I don't understand why it's not working. Is TYPO3 interfering? I though I would be safe if I write it as the first thing in my .htaccess.

Comment: `Redirect` doesn't match query string starting with `?`. Use `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention samples of urls FROM which you want to redirect/rewrite TO which url.

Comment: @anubhava Oh, I did not know that! That perfectly explains why the old typo3-urls don't work - thank you!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The website isn't public, but the domain remains the same which is why I didn't include it, since it is not necessary. But anubhava pointed out why it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 does not interfere as the rules in the `.htaccess` file are evaluated before.

Another option could be to use the redirect module of TYPO3 for creating the redirects. Those can then be created in the backend and maintained by editors. A small drawback is that performance is not that perfect as in `.htaccess` but it is much more convenient.